# Is Golang crypto/rand thread safe?

Tags: go, random, cryptography

The source of [math/rand.Rand](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.2:src/math/rand/rand.go;l=270) states `Read` is not thread safe (when sharing a source). What about [crypto/rand](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.2:src/crypto/rand/rand.go)? The source states it uses `getrandom(2)` or `/dev/urandom`, but it is unclear what happens with concurrent calls.

Update: comments have helped clarify the distinction

```golang
crypto/rand.Reader.Read(b []byte)
crypto/rand.Read(b []byte)
```

To be a thread safe:

1. Will it panic when `Read` is called concurrently?
2. Will it keep the random sequence when called concurrently? Or can duplicates be given to concurrent callers?

Comment: You mean `rand.Reader`? It's defined as a "global, shared instance of a cryptographically secure random number generator", so it has to be safe, since it's shared globally. You can't predict how it will be read from packages you don't control.

Comment: Also, the `Read` method you linked from `math/rand` is on a `Rand` struct, which contains other buffers for all its convenience methods, the `crypto/rand` source is just an `io.Reader`.

Comment: @JimB I'm mainly asking about using `Read`, which has no mutex around that `io.ReadFull` from `rand.Reader`.

Comment: The _function_ `rand.Read()` is safe for concurrent use (as documented). The _method_ `rand.Rand.Read()` is not.

Comment: @JoshHibschman, it doesn't need a mutex if the `io.Reader` itself is safe, the buffer it's filling with `ReadFull` is not going to be shared.

Comment: @icza oh right, sharing a random source is not safe, thank you. At this point then, I'm mainly curious about question 2 above.

Comment: thanks @JimB I think you might have just answered 2, feel free to post an answer

Comment: Using `crypto/rand`, there is no random sequence that could change or be repeated, no sense talking about it. If you use `math/rand.Read()`, then if you're not synchronizing the concurrent goroutines calling it, any execution order is valid, so again, you can't predict the sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [`rand.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand#pkg-variables) from `crypto/rand` must be safe for concurrent access, because it is defined as *"a global, shared instance of a cryptographically secure random number generator"*. There would be no way to synchronize its use between packages.
2. [`rand.Read`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand#Read) from `crypto/rand` is safe because the `rand.Reader` is safe, and it does not access any other shared state.